# Two side by side figures - Overleaf OK, Texmaker KO

Tags: graphics, texmaker, subcaption, overleaf

I wrote the following code and the result is ok on Overleaf, ko in Texmaker ('cat' 'elephant' not found):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{A cat\label{cat}}
{\includegraphics{cat}}
\subcaptionbox{An elephant\label{elephant}}
{\includegraphics{elephant}}
\caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Inside the folder where there is the tex file I created the folder Immagini and inside I put cat.png and elephant.png.

---

EDIT: log error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `cat' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22 {\includegraphics{cat}}
                            
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Comment: Please show the full error, preferably the entire log for this exact example. A lot of editors filters the log messages, and they don't always do a good job

Comment: Hello @daleif see the edit please

Comment: Exactly which compiler are you using? Seems you're using plain larex, you need pdflatex, plain latex does not support png. Overleaf uses pdflatex by default. Otherwise, as I mentioned, please provide the entire log

Comment: you are using latex. dvips can not include png files.

Comment: thank you for the comments; yes, I was using dvips. Now I'm using pdflatex, but I'm not able to see the preview in the pdf viewer of texmaker after the compiling. When I remove the embed option, the pdf viewer disappears. I will post another question about that